# Let OneToOneField to User only render one text input (for User.first_name) using a ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms

Suppose I have the following model with modelform:

```
MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    is_male = models.BooleanField(default=False)

MyModelForm(models.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ("user", # How to only insert a value for user.first_name?  
          "age")
```

How can a modelform use only one field (`first_name`) of a OneToOneField (`user`) of the Model it references to(`MyModel`)?

In other words, I would like **`MyModelForm` to render only a text input that passes a value to `user.first_name`**.

I don't see why it wouldn't be possible since I can do the following succesfully:

```
>>> john = User.objects.create(first_name="John")
```

Comment: You need to be a bit more clear. Are you hoping that the form will link the MyModel instance to an existing User with that first_name, or create a new User?

Comment: I'm hoping that it links to an existing user. So the last part of my question was actually misleading, sorry. I know I have to somehow pass information (request.user) to address the right table row. But I don't know where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote the question and adapted the code. The answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594419/elegantly-set-a-single-attribute-of-a-model-used-in-a-onetoonefield-using-a-mode).