# Elegantly set a single attribute of a Model used in a OneToOneField using a ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms

I am able to update the `height` attribute of `MyLittleModel` using `MyModelForm`(`OneToOneField(MyLittleModel)`) as follows:

**models.py**

```
class MyLittleModel(models.Model):
    height = models.IntegerField()
    has_color = models.NullBooleanField(null=True, blank=True)


class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_little_model = models.OneToOneField(MyLittleModel)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    is_male = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**forms.py**

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    height = forms.IntegerField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ("height", 
          "age")
```

**views.py**

```
class MyUpdateView(UpdateView):
    form_class = MyModelForm
    model = MyModel
    template_name = 'my_template.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        my_little_model = MyLittleModel.objects.create(form.cleaned_data["height"])
        form.instance.my_little_model = my_little_model
        form.instance.save()
        return super(MyUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("my_list_view")
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(regex=r'^update/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', view=MyUpdateView.as_view(), name="my_update_view"),
)
```

I think this is not a good coding style because this forces you to modify your code in the ModelForm as well as in the View, it would be preferable that this would happen in only one location.

**So is it possible to set a value to `my_little_model.height` without modifying my views code as I did?**

*Note*: I don't like the title to this question, if someone has a suggestion for renaming it  into something more readable please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this by overriding your `MyModelForm`'s save method, like so:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    height = forms.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ("height",
          "age")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        my_little_model = MyLittleModel.objects.create(height=self.cleaned_data["height"])
        self.instance.my_little_model = my_little_model
        self.instance.save()
        return super(MyModelForm2, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then your view becomes:

```
class MyUpdateView(UpdateView):
    template_name = "my_template.html"
    form_class = MyModelForm
    model = MyModel

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("my_list_view")
```

This way, all your logic for updating the model information lives in the form - if you want to change what's being updated, you can do it all in one place.

Comment: Thanks!! I changed my original case, it used a `User` object before, I changed this to `MyLittleModel` because otherwise `User` could give additional errors if the `save` method was used on an `Anonymous User`. I adapted your answer to my case.

Comment: There are a few mistakes in your code though, `super(self, MyModelForm)` instead of `super(MyModelForm, self)`. You also need to define `model`/`queryset`/`get_queryset` in your view because it's an `UpdateView` (you wouldn't need to in a `CreateView`, I made the same mistake btw). I tested the adaptation of your code and it works

Comment: Also note that overwriting `form_valid` is not necessary since the `form` is already saved by `UpdateView`'s [ModelFormMixin](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.5/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/). Nevertheless it's not a bad thing to make users aware that saving happens there.

Comment: @Bentley4 thanks for the tweaks! I've improved the answer with your changes.

Comment: If you are working with `User` instead of `MyLittleModel` you can access the current `User` in the `save` method of the `Modelform` by calling `self.instance.user` (similar to `self.request.user` in a view). Just thought I'd mention this for future reference, this was something useful in your previous version of your answer.